# django url patterns for project with multiple apps

Tags: python, django

I have a django project with multiple apps, right now I am having trouble getting the apps to work with each other, the problem is in my url schemes. ex. I click on a tab on the index page. I am forwarded to a url like: `Mysite/App1`.

Then I click on another link that is a different app. so now the url is like: `Mysite/App1/App2`. of course app2 can't be found, I can't seem to exit the app1 directory to go back to the root url conf, the url should be: `Mysite/App2`. If you could just make suggestions or link someone else's code so I can see an example of how it should work. thanks guys

root url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('App1.urls'))
]
```

App 1 url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('App1/', include(([
        path('NextLevel', views.NextLevel, name="Next Level")
    ])))

]
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you generate the link in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the app name in the apps own urls.py.

eg.

```
app_name = "app1"
```

Then you can reference the path as a reverse. In a template you would use:

```
<a href="{% url 'app1:next_level' %}">
```

Also:note that paths are evaluated in order, so your regex match of "^" will in fact match everything, so any link at all will be redirected to app1.urls.py. Make sure you link the most generic one at the end, and for a regex that matches blank use "^$".

Edited to add: When you set a name, no spaces, so all it "next_level", and you probably need to add "as_view() to the view you are linking to (though you don't post the view itself, but I'm assuming it's a relatively basic one).

i.e.

```
path('nextlevel/', views.NextLevel.as_view(), name="next_level"),
```